# What is the statement |x+y|≤|x|+|y| saying

Tags: discrete-mathematics

```
|x+y|≤|x|+|y|
```

I know that |x| means the cardinality of x for example. But it looks to me like its saying the cardinality of x plus y is less then or equal to the cardinality of x plus y... Is that what the statement is trying to say?

Thanks

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality.

Comment: $|\cdot|$ means the absolute value in this context. It denotes the cardinality when its argument is a set.

Comment: Within geometry it simply states the basic theorem: in any (euclidean, of course) triangle, the sum of any two sides' lengths is bigger than the third side's length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of two sets is their union. It follows, that $$|X\cup Y|\leq|X|+|Y|$$ Where equality holds when $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint.

In some cases, the sum of sets is in fact considered to be their disjoint union to begin with. But it should be indicated what is the precise meaning of $+$ in this context somewhere in the text, or at least the context should be set in such way that an informed reader can tell the meaning of the symbol.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused because I couldn't think of a reason why x+y would need the || around them.

Comment: It seems more likely that the original statement refers to sums of numbers rather than unions of sets, especially since the notation OP used was $x$ and $y$, not $X$ and $Y$, don't you think?

Comment: @MPW: I disagree. $x$ and $y$ are also sets. The question was posted in the context of discrete mathematics, and the OP explicitly said that $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality of a set.

Comment: It's possible of course. I wouldn't have thought so--but I didn't notice the tag. That lends more weight to your interpretation, to be sure. Now I am less confident of my suggestion...